# getline c++ need assistance

Tags: c++, input, inputstream, iostream

I'm trying to read individual lines to different variables and I'm having trouble having it read anything past the first line

```
ifstream inputFileStream;
inputFileStream.open( fileName );
if (inStream.good() && inStream.open())
    {
        string empNum;
        string name;
        string streetAddress;

        getline(inStream, empNum);
        getline(inStream, name);
        getline(inStream, streetAddress);

cout <<empNum << endl;
cout <<name << endl;
cout <<streetAddress << endl;


}
```

Also the txt file looks like this:

```
12  
Bob  
123 Main  
555-555
```

Comment: You haven't checked that the reads succeeded.

Comment: What does the program display ?

Comment: Did you actually mean to display `hoursWorked` and `hourWage`?

Comment: i just want to read them in from the file and display to console. When I debug, however, I only see the first variable receiving the first line, the rest dont get anything i can see

Comment: Are you receiving any errors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code works for me. copy & paste & run (without changes...)

```
#include <fstream> 
#include <iostream> 
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    ifstream inputFileStream("text.txt");

    if (inputFileStream.good() )
    {
        string empNum;
        string name;
        string streetAddress;

        getline(inputFileStream, empNum);
        getline(inputFileStream, name);
        getline(inputFileStream, streetAddress);

        cout <<empNum << endl;
        cout <<name << endl;
        cout <<streetAddress << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```